# shell_exec not working when excuted from browser | ssh | scp | keygen

Tags: php, shell, ssh, shell-exec

What I want to do is:

1. execute "shellUnlock.php" from browser
2. then "scriptUNLOCK.sh" executed from the "shellUnlock.php"
3. then "resultUNLOCK.log" created from the scriptUNLOCK.sh
4. then show "resultUNLOCK.log" in browser

Notes:

- For the SSH i used keygen, so i don't have to insert any password again from my server.
- I used the SCP to copy "resultUNLOCK.log" created in "da.serv.er" to my own folder.
- I have try it from browser, but it shows no output at all.
- The script works well when I execute from putty but from shell_exec it's not work.
- And I don't have access to install anything in the server.

**my "shellUnlock.php" file**

```
$myfile = fopen("nameUSER.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "USERNAME";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
shell_exec('./scriptUNLOCK.sh');
if (file_exists("resultUNLOCK.log"))
   echo readfile("resultUNLOCK.log");
}else{
   echo "Please Try";
}
```

**my "scriptUNLOCK.sh" script**

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='user@da.serv.er'
HOME='/home/web/UNLOCK'
DIR='/somewhere/script/UNLOCK/'

cd ${HOME}
while read nameUSER
do
ssh ${HOST} <<END_SCRIPT
cd ${DIR}
unlock.sh ${nameUSER} > resultUNLOCK.log
exit
END_SCRIPT
cd ${HOME}
scp ${HOST}:${DIR}resultUNLOCK.log ${HOME}
done < nameUSER.txt
```

Now please help me. I'm totally confused. Thanks.

Comment: It may be issue with permissions. Dose the webserver user has write permission to log file

Comment: I would say that it might be a permission problem. If you successfully execute the shell script from the command line, but it doesn't work from webpage, it's probably because in the first case you are running it with user privileges, while in the second case it's apache user...

Comment: Would you mind to put an output of `ls -la /somewhere/script/UNLOCK/` here?

Answer (score 0):

If the script works fine when running it from the command line but it doesn't when you trigger it via your webserver it has to be a permission or/and path problem.

Ensure that the apache user (either www-data, www or apache by default) has write access to the UNLOCK folder and I think it will work.
And you should probably change the name of your "HOME" variable since HOME is a fix environment variable in Linux. I don't know if this is a problem, but i would change the name nevertheless to avoid disorder.

Best way would be to make it via groups

```
    sudo usermod -a -G www-data <apache_user>
    sudo chgrp -R www-data /somewhere/script/UNLOCK/
    sudo chmod -R g+w /somewhere/script/UNLOCK/
```

So at least the user you use to login via putty must have the rights to modify the accessibility of the directory. If not, you can either contact your system administrator or use another folder you have access on.

I hope this helps.
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved!

Instead using shell_exec in php, i directly execute the script using crontab.
I'm sure I can find other best solution to solve this case if I have no limited time.
But the time forces me. :D
Well at least IT WORKS!

Thanks all..!

Comment: What a hideous solution. 
I would really recommend you to give it at least a try, it will take you 5 minutes: 1. give the full path to the shellscript 2. set permissions. cheers

Comment: i've done that 2 steps dude, and it's still not work. That's why i decide the hideous solution. lol.